# Camera rotation and translation from tracking?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

What is the best way to find camera rotation and translation from tracking the scene without calibrating the camera?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you will skip *calibration* because you get the translation and rotation from the calibration process. Maybe instead of using two cameras you'll compare frame 0 to frame 1000 from the same (moving) camera, but the calibration process is the same.

Check out [Chapter 11 in the Learning OpenCV](http://books.google.com/books?id=seAgiOfu2EIC&lpg=PA405&dq=learning%20opencv%20chapter%2011&pg=PA405#v=onepage&q&f=false) book.  If you want to skip *lens correction,* check the section heading "Computing extrinsics only." The function is `cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams2`.